# How should I present a common Minimal Working Example for multiple questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, code

I have several questions for the same piece of code. Should I present the Minimal Working Example in a question and provide a link to it from the other questions, or it is better to copy the MWE to all questions?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the usual standard terminology here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, I think there should be one working code snippet per coding question.

If you are going to ask multiple questions on one piece of code I suspect that it may need to be broken down some more first.

Also, if you are wanting to ask multiple questions about a piece of code maybe what you are seeking is a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I was thinking of a situation where every part works, but not the whole combination. Moreover, changing something affects something else that seems irrelevant. There are 2-3 questions about it, but they cannot be grouped to a single question.

Mayby Code Review is the best solution.